# "I won't be attending" or "I won't attend"?

Tags: tense

In which cases should these two similar sentences be used (i.e., future progressive vs. future simple)?

Comment: Typically, the first means you won't be *able* to attend, the second states your *refusal* to attend.

Answer (score 1):

You might use the first in a conversation about a specific future event: 
I won't be attending the proposed meeting next Wednesday to discuss felafels.'

You might use the second in a conversation about a decision you have reached about a particular type of event: 
'I won't attend Disney-themed weddings.'

However, they are somewhat interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

It is like, "Will you attend the meeting?" One said, "I won't attend." This is a definitive answer. The other person replied, "I am not sure; most probably, I won't". It is like, "As it stands now, I won't be attending."  These are the minimum interpretations.  There are also other situations when Simple Future and Future Continuous can be used.